# Edit without changes?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56375204/revisions) edit summary of revision 2 says "added 2 characters in body" but I can't see any changes in any of "inline", "side-by-side" and "side-by-side markdown" tabs. Bug?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
curl -k https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ca33301c-617b-4f8d-bbeb-01f29355a441/view-source > ~/ver1
curl -k https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16350f57-3305-42f4-bc0d-623fcef90e24/view-source > ~/ver2

hexdump -C ~/ver1
#snip
00000100  6c 65 3f 3c 2f 70 72 65  3e 0d 0a 3c 2f 62 6f 64  |le?</pre>..</bod|
#snip

hexdump -C ~/ver2
#snip
00000100  6c 65 3f 0d 0a 3c 2f 70  72 65 3e 0d 0a 3c 2f 62  |le?..</pre>..</b|
#snip
```

The edit adds two new ASCII characters, 0x0D (carriage return) 0x0A (newline).

Comment: Oh, newline... Using curl is cool!